# Onsen UI : ons-col width

Tags: html, css, layout, onsen-ui

I want to have two columns of - one 40% - second: 60% in onsen ui

here is my code and its not working

```
<ons-row>
  <ons-col size="40">Col</ons-col>
  <ons-col >Col</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

i also tried with

```
<ons-row>
  <ons-col >Col</ons-col>
  <ons-col size="60">Col</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

and

```
<ons-row>
  <ons-col size="40">Col</ons-col>
  <ons-col size="60">Col</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

All not working

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards

Comment: can you make it worked?

Comment: nope - tried your answer  too - it dint worked

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
<ons-row>
 <ons-col width="50px">Col</ons-col>
 <ons-col >Col</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

Comment: go to http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html and find the `Layout` portion. described there

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `width: 40%`?

```
<ons-row>
    <ons-col width="40%">I'm 40%</ons-col>
    <ons-col>I'm 60%</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/tranduyhung/pen/pvJjZB